# Free Trail on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I recently signed up for the free trial on Google Cloud Platform using my Mastercard. I keep getting an error that they do not accept pre-paid cards. However,this is after they kept billing me $1.00 for every attempt i made to sign up for the free trial. This has happened to me TWICE.Please Help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question, but a question that you should be raising with someone from the billing apartement of your cloud provider.

Answer (score 1):

It's written, "Prepaid cards are not accepted for payment.".

Source: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6293589?hl=en

You have to use "debit cards with the Visa or MasterCard logo" in order to sign up for a free trial.